# Inherit form of res.partner

Tags: odoo

I create a new class fleet_agent that inherits from res.partner without problems

```
class fleet_agent(osv.Model): 
    _name = 'fleet.agent'
    _inherit = ['res.partner']
    _columns = {
    'test': fields.char('Test', help='Test'),
}
```

then fleet_agent_form inherits base.view_partner_form also no problem

```
<record id="fleet_agent_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
            <field name="name">fleet.agent.form</field>
            <field name="model">fleet.agent</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="state_id" position="before">
                    <field name="x" />
                </field>
            </field>
</record>
```

My problem is that this form does not appear as the formatting of view_partner_form and with all fields without any order ?

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new model 'fleet.agent' by extending the base 'res.partner'. In order to show all the fields, you need to specify the fields in xml or use the classical inheritance by removing 'fleet.agent' and add your field to the base 'res.partner'.

```
class fleet_agent(osv.Model): 
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
              'field': fields.char('Name', help='help'),
    }
```

In xml file:

```
<field name="model">fleet.agent</field>
```

Comment: i want to create a new class fleet.agent with new table from res.partner model by _inherit and using the same base.view_partner_form with new fleet.agent fields.

Comment: Ok then define `_name='fleet.agent'` in python code and define `_inherits = {'res.partner' : 'fleet_agent_id'}` and in view you can access all the fields of res.partner. You need to provide field definition for fleet_agent_id as well. see the product.product class for reference and it's view, there is `product_tmpl_id` is referring the `product.template`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Partner(model.Model): 
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    test = fields.Char(string='Test', help='Test'),
}

<record id="fleet_agent_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
            <field name="name">partner.test</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <field name="test" />
            </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
class fleet_agent(osv.Model): 
    _inherit = ['res.partner']
    _columns = {
    'test': fields.char('Test', help='Test'),
}

<record id="fleet_agent_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
    <field name="name">fleet.agent.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="state_id" position="before">
            <field name="x" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Remove `_name = 'fleet.agent'` from your python code, it's create new model, and in xml when you extend any parent model you must write parent model name into the view

```
<field name="model">res.partner</field>
```

So you will get extended functionality with your base class's functionality.

Comment: i want to create a new class fleet.agent with new table from res.partner model by _inherit and using the same base.view_partner_form with new fleet.agent fields.

Answer (score 0):

To copy table to your moule you should use **inherits** keyword instead of **inherit**. Also you have to copy view definition of partner form of base module and change it, extending wouldn't help you in creating new table.
[Source](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/whats-the-difference-between-inherit-and-inherits-52205)

Update: additional information on ways os inheritance:

### Update2: looks like you're on right way: there is a [third](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/the-different-openerp-model-inheritance-mechanisms-what-s-the-difference-between-them-and-when-should-they-be-used-46) way of inheritance: with **inherit** keyword and by specifying new _name for new model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use:

```
class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    test = fields.Char(string='test')`
```

2. Upgrade module from console:

```
./odoo-bin -u [module_name] -c [configuration_file
```